# This robot has a joint named "joint_1" which is not in the gazebo model

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
There is also a topic "This robot has a joint named "foo" which is not in the gazebo model."[link](http://answers.ros.org/question/102276/this-robot-has-a-joint-named-foo-which-is-not-in-the-gazebo-model/)
But it didn't help.
I get the following error;

```
[ERROR] [1467817563.508002714, 0.339000000]: This robot has a joint named "joint_1" which is not in the gazebo model.
[FATAL] [1467817563.508348807, 0.339000000]: Could not initialize robot simulation interface
```

My corresponding URDF file part is;

```
<robot name="itecharm">

  <link name="world"/>

  <joint name="fixed" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="link_base"/>
  </joint>


  <link name="link_base">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="-0.0325856 5.11013e-06 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="1.26763"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.00165595" ixy="-8.29854e-06" ixz="-3.99028e-11" iyy="0.00129758" iyz="1.56383e-07" izz="0.00130449"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="-0.0742893 -0.0873818 0.0157596" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://itecharm_description/meshes/link_base.STL"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="link_base_color">
        <color rgba="0.792157 0.819608 0.933333 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="-0.0742893 -0.0873818 0.0157596" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://itecharm_description/meshes/link_base.STL"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link name="link_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0.137802209307 0.090396 0.0227196811405" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.137802209307 0.090396 0.0227196811405" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://itecharm_description/meshes/link_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="link_1_color">
        <color rgba="0.792157 0.819608 0.933333 1.0"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.137802209307 0.090396 0.0227196811405" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://itecharm_description/meshes/link_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="joint_1" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="-0.0688 0 0" rpy="0 0.261799319827 1.57079632679"/>
    <axis xyz="-2.22044604925e-16 1.0 0.0"/>
    <parent link="link_base"/>
    <child link="link_1"/>
    <limit effort="50000" lower="-3.14159265359" upper="3.14159265359" velocity="50000"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.1"/>
  </joint>
```

Also, the transmission part of the URDF;

```
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/itecharm</robotNamespace>
      <!--<robotSimType>ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>-->
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

 <transmission name="trans_1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint_1">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="joint_servo_1">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      <mechanicalReduction>100</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
```

I have another URDF file for a simple two R robot that works. I couldn't figure out why this doesn't. I spawned the robot in Rviz  and checked the joints without any problem. I am using ROS-Indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238899/this-robot-has-a-joint-named-%22joint_1%22-which-is-not-in-the-gazebo-model./) by [Oguz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21418/oguz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2016-07-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After changing the

```
   <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0.137802209307 0.090396 0.0227196811405" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.0" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0"/>
    </inertial>
```

part, giving random values to mass and inertia, the problem is gone.

---

Originally posted by [Oguz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21418/oguz/) with karma: 121 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew Price](https://answers.ros.org/users/3629/andrew-price/) on 2018-03-17**:
Also, Gazebo will round sufficiently small numbers to 0, so you may encounter this problem even with a nonzero mass/inertia.